# What is the replacement of anko bg?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the anko bg functionality to manage background task.

The code is as following

```
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Response
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result
import org.jetbrains.anko.coroutines.experimental.bg

object AuthenticationService {
    suspend fun login(login: Login): Triple<Request, Response, Result<GenResponse, FuelError>> {
        return bg {
            HttpService.post<GenResponse>("/auth/login",login.toJsonString())
        }.await()
    }
}
```

it is showing bg is deprecated and asking me to use `async(block)`

how to replace this background task with async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`s for different kinds of background tasks and using them as coroutine dispatchers.

And you always can take a look at [Anko `bg` source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/b036b59aa5d9d24dc49ad2dfcc57fe4114436175/anko/library/generated/coroutines/src/main/java/bg.kt) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any replacement for `bg` because Fuel supports async HTTP. You don't need any background thread to perform requests. Additionally, Fuel has [first-class support for coroutines](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/blob/master/fuel-coroutines/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

as per the info, you should just replace it with coroutine's async. 
Probably something among the lines of:

```
return async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            HttpService.post<GenResponse>("/auth/login",login.toJsonString())
        }.await()
```

Let me know if it helps :)!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
suspend fun login(login: Login): Triple<Request, Response, Result<GenResponse, FuelError>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            HttpService.postNoAuth<GenResponse>("/auth/login", login.toJsonString())
        }
    }
```